# Forgotten questions due to spam waves

Tags: discussion, support

A while ago, we were having some spam waves, do to the distraction, we didn't answer the question, that were getting spam A's. I checked my flags, and saw some of them are completely forgotten, I tried to bring attention to them, by editing them.

But, am not always here so other Q/A that were getting spammed in my absence, may still be forgotten some where.

My suggestion is, check your `flag-summary`, and try to improved some of the Q's or answer them.